# didDeselectItemAt For UIcollectionView is not called but didSelectItemAt is called?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a multi selection for UICollectionView.  The delegate function didSelectItemAt is called but didDeselectItemAt is NEVER called and I do not know why?  I am not even sure how it works.  If I click on a cell - didSelectItemAt is called.  So if I click once again on the same cell is didDeselectItemAt supposed to be called?

My UIViewController inherits and conforms to all of the following: UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

viewdidLoad():

```
collectionView.allowsSelection = true
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Delegate functions:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didSelectItemAt")

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("DESELECT")
}
```

Comment: that’s the functionality of didSelect. didDeselect will be called when you select another cell. What you are asking for has to be custom implemented

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla - thank you for your response.  But in this instance  'didDeselectItemAt 'is NEVER called whatever i click.

Comment: @matt - the answer below seems to contradict what you have stated. I just don't know why the delegate function 'didDeselectItemAt' is just not called despite allowsMultipleSelection is set to 'true' (even though didSelectItemAt is called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your code is different from what you have shown us, and in that in your real code, you have not given the correct signature for `didDeselect`. Here's why. Look carefully at the code you have shown:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("didSelectItemAt")

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("DESELECT")
}
```

Now ask yourself: Why did the compiler permit the second `func` to stand, even though you *forgot to say `override`*? I'm guessing it's because it is *not* an override. There is something wrong with the signature, so it's just a meaningless function that doesn't conform to UICollectionViewDelegate.

Try using code completion to re-enter this function. If all goes well, it will be an override and it will start working.

---

To illustrate more precisely: This compiles, but the second method will never be called:

```
class CV : UICollectionViewController {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectItemAt")
    }
    func colectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("DESELECT")
    }
}
```

But this doesn't compile, because the signature is correct but we forgot `override`:

```
class CV : UICollectionViewController {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectItemAt")
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("DESELECT")
    }
}
```

But in that second one, if we *do* say `override`, it compiles *and works*.

Comment: Holy moly.  It was the absence of OVERRIDE. lesson learned.  Thank you so much.

Comment: But, as I say, without `override` your code should never have compiled in the first place; if it did, I don't understand why.

Comment: I think it compiled because my UICollectionView was a custom one that was a subclass of a custom Generic class of UICollectionView that I wrote.  To solve the issue I added the didDeselectItemAt function to my Generic class of   UICollectionView, then added the override to the child class that I am actually using (above).  So before the fix, my Generic class did not have didSelectItemAt, and by subclassing it and forgetting to add the override, it compiled....

Comment: The OP has a `UIViewController` that implements `UICollectionViewDelegate` not a `UICollectionViewController` so there is no need to add `override`. (And would trigger a compiler error since there is nothing to override.)

Comment: @JasonMoore No, because for the OP `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt` _does_ compile. The inconsistency revealed the true source of the issue, which the OP did not expose until a later comment. The flaw was in the OPs own generic subclass, which we we were not told about in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/issues/400) open issue on Github.

It could be that you have a tap gesture recognizer on a view in the same hierarchy that contains your collection view. Remove the tap gesture and see if that works. This happened to be my issue.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(...) // your tap gesture recognizer
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) // what you already have
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: This is a very frustrating issue and that's probably why I was downvoted -- however, after facing this issue at least a few more times, it has become clear that this is a frequent issue and my posted solution is a well-documented one

Comment: Your answer mainly deals with `didSelectItemAt` not being called, while the OP's question is about `didDeselectItemAt` not being called. However, I believe that in this context your answer might help people who are stuck around these two calls.

Comment: What if you used UIBuilder to add the GestureRecognizer, then how do you identify it?  You should include both what's inside the (...) and the context.  This is probably the issue, but one wouldn't know how to fix it from just this, or where to put the code.  Inside didSelectItemAt? In the viewDidLoad? viewWillAppear?  Without specificity, we're on another goose chase to figure out all the nuances of GestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

if `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false` // default then you have to tap on a different cell in order to deselect the previous one.

if `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` // only tapping on **the same** cell triggers deselect delegate method

Comment: The explanantion is clear and makes perfect sense.  But I have tested this but didDeselectItemAt is NEVER called (didSelectItemAt is called)...even though collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true.  Would you know why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this changed recently, but with iOS13 it seems that simply specifying that a collection view cell is selected when the cell is dequeued is not enough for the collection view to allow you to deselect the cell. You need to **also** manually tell the collection view to select the cell.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: photoCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.isSelected = true
    if cell.isSelected {
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
    }
}
```

I figured this out because i was able to select and deselect cells, but was not able to deselect a cell that was initially selected.